# Find all files whose absolute path ends in a certain pattern

Tags: find, filepath, glob

Using `find` and globbing, how can I find all files in a given directory whose absolute path (or even just path relative to the given directory) ends in `/foldername/otherfolder/*.php`?

Comment: Not clear from the question whether you literary mean a single level glob to start, or just files for which the whole path ends in `/foldername/otherfolder/*.php`. I took it to mean the latter. Otherwise you can just use `-path` or omit `find` altogether and do `echo */foldername/otherfolder/*.php`

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. You were right - it was the latter.

Comment: No problem, updated question slightly to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean files, for which the whole path ends in `/foldername/otherfolder/*.php`, you can just use the `-regex` option

```
find -regex '.*/foldername/otherfolder/[^/]*.php'
```

Where `-regex` will operate on either the relative or absolute path (depending on what you provided, with default being relative to `$PWD`) and use `emacs` type.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. I must have overlooked the regex option in the man page.

Comment: It turns out that for some reason the regex option isn't recognized on my system (Mac/10.9.4). I'm trying to use the option `-E` which is supposed to do the same thing, but it just prints out every single file. Here's what I'm giving it: `find -E / '^.*php/configure$'` Any hints?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius There should still be a `-regex` option on `BSD find`, try `find -E -regex ...`

Comment: It still gives me "illegal option r". If I figure it out, I'll post it here. For now I'm just going to forget about it.